# syntax error on openvz to execute command in all vps

Tags: syntax, openvz

as per the document of openvz, I am trying to execute uptime command across all vps, but I am getting syntax error

```
# echo "vps $i"; vzctl exec $i uptime; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `vzlist –o veid -H`; do echo "vps $i"; vzctl exec $i uptime; done
```